# "Missing arugment for parameter 'param' in call" for a lazy variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to initialise an empty variable (of type a custom class) in Swift. Google has told me to use the 'lazy' keyword, but I'm getting the error "Missing argument for parameter 'name' in call":

```
lazy var currentEvent = Event()
```

Where an event is:

```
class Event {
    let name: String
    let venue: String
    let description: String
    let startTime: String
    let coords: [Float]
    let tags: [String]
    let friendsAttending: Int
    let imageURL: String
    var seen: Bool

func setSeen(seen: Bool) {
    self.seen = seen
}

init(name: String, venue: String, description: String, startTime: String, coords: [Float], tags: [String],
    friendsAttending: Int, imageURL: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.venue = venue
        self.description = description
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.coords = coords
        self.tags = tags
        self.friendsAttending = friendsAttending
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.seen = false
        GlobalVariables.imageCache.fetch(URL: NSURL(string: imageURL)!)
    }
}
```

Am I using the keyword wrong (and how do I initialise an empty variable otherwise), or does my class need to implement something else to be lazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you haven't defined the initializer `Event()` (without parameters). You have only defined the initializer `Event(name: , venue: , description: , startTime: , coords: , tags: , friendsAttending: , imageURL: )`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, if I give Event an empty `init()` then that initialising function says I'm not initialising `self.name` (I tried making it a variable instead of a constant but same error).

Comment: Ah, I seemed to have fixed it by initialising all the member variables (of Event) as empty variables themselves... crazy!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.